# how to mock an external function in ezyme or jest testing

Tags: function, testing, jestjs, mocking, enzyme

// Component.js

```
render () {
const isEventAccessible = checkAccess(area);
if(isEventAccessible ){
  return(<div>No access</div);
}
return (<div>Acess</div>);

//checkAccess.js 

export const checkAccess = (a) => {
if(a==1){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;  
}

}
```

I want to create two snapshots one for No Access view & one for Access but i can't pass checkAccess  function in props how can i mock this function please help..????

Comment: Is this like useful? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Answer (score 0):

In your test file, mock the module function with

```
import { checkAccess } from '<path to your module file>/checkAccess'; 
jest.mock('<path to your module file>/checkAccess')
```

and in your test let the mock return the value with `mockReturnValue`:

```
it('should render "No access"', () => {
  checkAccess.mockReturnValue(true); // mock will return true
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  expect(getByText('No access')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```